# Draw radius lines in circle with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how I could draw a line from the center of the circle outward to the border based on a given degree. (I'd eventually want a line every 30 degrees resulting in 12 total lines)

Below is a picture of something similar to what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

CSS for the circle I have currently:

```
.circle-container{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15.5%;
    left: 14.5%;
    background: #fff;
    width: 11.5em;
    height: 11.5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;
    margin: 0em;
}
```

I'm not really sure where I should start.

Comment: I'd use SVG...otherwise you'll end up with a LOT of unsemantic elements just for styling purposes.

Comment: or the canvas element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use Canvas or SVG...otherwise you'll end up with a LOT of unsemantic elements just for styling purposes.

However, a brief example

```css
.circle-container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15.5%;
  left: 14.5%;
  background: #fff;
  width: 11.5em;
  height: 11.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #bfbfbf;
  margin: 0em;
}
.radius {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.two {
  background: green;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
  <div class="radius"></div>
  <div class="radius two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a line by setting the height property to 0, the width to `50%`, which is half the diameter and creating a border.

To transform, you will want to use the `rotate` property along with `transform-origin`.

Here is a simple example.

```js
var radius = document.getElementById("radius");
var rotate = document.getElementById("rotate");

var rotation = 0;

rotate.addEventListener("click", function() {
    rotation -= 30;
    radius.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
    radius.style.transformOrigin = "center right";
});
```

```css
.circle-container{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15.5%;
    left: 14.5%;
    background: #fff;
    width: 11.5em;
    height: 11.5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;
    margin: 0em;
}

#radius {
  height: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
  <div id="radius"></div>
</div>

<button id="rotate">Rotate Radius</button>
```

As for as having a line for every 30 degrees, let's think about that. A circle is 360 degrees, which means we would need 12 lines. In HTML this would require a lot of overhead. For this, we would have to do a lot of DOM manipulation.

For that, I would recommend Canvas, or one of the JavaScript canvas libraries like `jcanvas`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something super flexible, I'd do something like this...you can add another .line with an ID and give each one a separate rotation to get all your angles in.

```
.line{
    width: 1px;
    height: 50%;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.line:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #000;
}

<div class="circle-container">
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Canvas element or SVG would be easier, but if you only want to use CSS styling of simple HTML elements, take a look at this tutorial for creating a css clock:
 https://cssanimation.rocks/clocks/

Answer (score -1):

another solution would be to clone the lines , as you said, you need 12 lines

see here: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/nfmgo720/2/)**

JQ:

```
var degr = 0;
var rotation = 0;
//create a rotate function
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};
//clone the lines
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
    $(".line").clone().appendTo(".circle-container")
}


//rotate the lines
$('.line').each(function() {

degr += 30;
$(this).rotate(degr);
});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="circle-container">
    <div class="line">

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS added :

```
.circle-container:before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:#000;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:calc(50% - 15px);
  border-radius:100%;
}
.circle-container .line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: #000;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```